# How to use discord.py regardless of events?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I need to use discord.py regardless of the events inside my program, and specifically get the user's id by his nickname (they are all on the same server).  bot.loop.create_task doesn't work for me, as it needs to start an event loop and my program is not related to event handling.
I will be glad to any of your help

Comment: `discord.py` uses an asynchronous http library.  There's no way to run it synchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory there is no way, because `discord.py` is asynchronous.

In practice...
you can try `discord.ext.tasks` and setup something that looks like a chron task.

Comment: Is it possible in some other way to accomplish my task?

Comment: Maybe, but this is the only one that comes to mind.

Comment: On another note, you can just have a blocking for/while loop with asynchronous functions inside.